# How to query a self-referencing has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following model:

```
class PropertyType < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :parent, :class_name => "PropertyType"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :properties
end
```

It can have a parent of it's own class type. However none of the following queries appear to work:

```
PropertyType.where("property_type_id IS NULL")
PropertyType.where(parent: nil)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What does your database schema look like for that model.

Comment: Yeah, hard to tell without context and schema. Specifically, what doesn't work? Are you getting an error or the wrong/empty result?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want a `:belongs_to` rather than a `:has_one`. You may want to also consider using naming foreign key so the direction of the relationship is more clear. In this case you would need to explicitly specify the foreign key:

```
class ProjectType
 belongs_to :parent, class_name: "ProjectType", foreign_key: :parent_project_type_id
 has_many :children, class_name: "ProjectType", foreign_key: :parent_project_type_id

 # ...
end
```